# Find SubStrings Between Given Two Regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I want to take all of the substrings inside of string which is between given two regex. Couple examples:

```
My $$name$$ is John, my $$surname$$ is Doe -> should return [name, surname]

My &&name&& is John, my &&surname&& is Doe -> should return again [name, surname]
```

I have tried couple solutions but non of them works for multiple substring with given dynamic values. How can I do that?

Comment: I understand that you have some sort of delimiters for your variables? and you want to extract what's between them? Or, you know what you want to read from that string and you just want to read it? Your question is unclear

Comment: _"which is between given two regex"_ - what regex? If you are only referring to the `$$` - those are not a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expression groups you can extract the values between a specified delimiter and then capturing a group in between those delimiters.

Works by creating a regex such as `\$\$(\w+)\$\$` using the specified delimiter.

```js
function matchSubstrings(input, delim) {
  // Used to escape regex operators, works by wrapping the token
  // in a [] (set). Prepending a \ is problematic.
  function escape(unescaped) {
    return unescaped.split("").map(v => `[${v}]`).join("");
  }
 
  const escapedDelim = escape(delim);
  return [...input.matchAll(new RegExp(`${escapedDelim}(\\w+)${escapedDelim}`, "g"))]?.map(v => v[1]) ?? [];
}

console.log(matchSubstrings("My $$name$$ is John, my $$surname$$ is Doe", "$$"));
console.log(matchSubstrings("My &&name&& is John, my &&surname&& is Doe", "&&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex : `(?<=\$\$|\&\&)(\w+)(?=\$\$|\&\&)`

Explanation :

`(?<=r)d` : matches a `d` only if is preceded by an `r`, but `r` will not be part of the overall regex match.

`d(?=r)`  : matches a `d` only if is followed by `r`, but `r` will not be part of the overall regex match.

```js
const regex = /(?<=\$\$|\&\&)(\w+)(?=\$\$|\&\&)/gm;

const str = "My $$name$$ is John, my $$surname$$ is Doe";
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        if (groupIndex > 0)
        console.log(match);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
/(?<=\$\$)[\w_]+(?=\$\$)|(?<=&&)[\w_]+(?=&&)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/j4iR9O/2

The idea is to use two patterns (one for `$$` and one for `&&`).
This can be done with the `|` syntax.

Then, I'm using a positive lookbehind `(?<=   )` to search for the `$$` that
I have to escape with a slash because `$` has a meaning in regular expressions.

For the positive lookahead, it's `(?=   )`.

In the middle, I want to match any word character or underscores (as it's a
variable name). This leads to `[\w_]+` meaning word char or underscores, at
least once or several times.

```js
const regex = /(?<=\$\$)[\w_]+(?=\$\$)|(?<=&&)[\w_]+(?=&&)/g;

const str = `My \$\$name\$\$ is John, my \$\$surname\$\$ is Doe -> should return [name, surname]
My &&name&& is John, my &&surname&& is Doe -> should return again [name, surname]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```